# How to show that the labour supply curve will not be negatively sloped?

Tags: derivatives, economics

Given $$U(c,1-h)=log\left (c-\frac{Bh^{1+\gamma}}{1+\gamma}  \right ),$$

where $B>0$,$\gamma \geq0$, $h$ denotes the household's optimal labour supply and $c$ denotes consumption. The budget constraint of the household is $c=wh + W$, where $w$ is the real wage and $W$ is wealth.

I have to find out why the labour supply curve will not be negatively sloped.

My attempts: I have solved for optimal choice of labour supply, $$h^{*} = \left (\frac{w}{B}  \right )^{\frac{1}{\gamma}}$$.

To find the slope, I have taken the derivative of the labour supply with respect to $w$.

$$\frac{\mathrm{d} h^{*}}{\mathrm{d} w} = w^{\frac{1 - \gamma}{\gamma}} \frac{1}{\gamma B^{\frac{1}{\gamma}}}.$$

So I need to show that $\frac{\mathrm{d} h^{*}}{\mathrm{d} w} \geq 0$ to show that the labour supply curve will not be negatively sloped. Any hints on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Assuming the wage is non-negative, $w, \gamma , B$ are all non-negative so the derivative you have taken must be non-negative.

Comment: Also, $h^*$ is clearly an increasing function of $w$.

Comment: @AnyAD Thanks for the comments. Do I explain that $w$ is non-negative by taking a log transformation of the labour supply function? Doing so gives $ln(h) = ln(B)^{\frac{-1}{\gamma}} + ln(w)^{\frac{1}{\gamma}}$. From here, I can see clearly that $w$ must be strictly positive otherwise the natural log function is not defined. The problem I have is with $\gamma \geq 0$. If $\gamma = 0$ then the derivative of the labour supply curve wrt $w$ does not exist.

Comment: @OGC I have another term for $h^*$. Are you sure about your result?

Comment: @OGC And the expression $Bh^{\color{red}{1-\gamma}}$ is right?

Comment: @callculus Oh sorry. It's actually $Bh^{1+\gamma}$. Good catch! I've made an edit. But the solution $h^{*}$ is correct. It was just a typo in the utility function.

Comment: @OGC OK. As far as I see the derivative is non-negative only if $\gamma>0$. For $\gamma=0$ the derivative is not defined.

Comment: @callculus Yes, that's what I think as well. It is stated in my comment to AnyAD. That's why I wanted to take the logarithm on both sides. But still there's a problem. Maybe apply L'Hopital's rule? Not sure how it will exactly help.

Comment: @OGC I think your $\ln(h)=...$ is not right. Beside that, $\gamma$ must be greater than $0$ since $h^*=\left( \frac{w}{B} \right)^{\frac1{\gamma}}$. Here you have a fraction as well, where $\gamma$ is the denominator. This means it is defined only for $\gamma>0$

Comment: @callculus Yes, you're right about $ln(h)$. It should $ln(h) = \frac{1}{\gamma}\left [ ln(w) - ln(B)\right ]$. I think probably then I have to take the derivative. This discussion in comments is getting long so please post an answer if you wish. Thanks.

Comment: @OGC Yes. Do you agree that $\gamma >0$ rather than $\gamma \geq 0$?

Comment: @callculus I agree, but I think I have to raise the issue to the instructor who is the one who came up with the assumptions of the parameters.

Comment: @OGC That´s a great idea.

Comment: @callculus I think it should be $\gamma \geq 1$ instead. Then we will have $\frac{\mathrm{d} h^{*}}{\mathrm{d} w} = \frac{1}{B} > 0$.